# How can I find last used column in formatted table?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the last used column in my formatted table and insert a value. But it's always returning the very last (=empty) column inside the table. See picture below for understanding:
[image]

For some reason, the text "- seit -" is placed into the column "10.Besitzer" in column 16 whereas it should have been put into "1.Besitzer" in column 7.

My code looks as following:

```
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 '+1 to go to next empty row 

'here it adds values in empty row, starting from column 1(ID) until column 6(IT). 
'I left out this part of code.
 
LastCol = ws.Cells(LastRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Search for last column
        
ws.Cells(LastRow, LastCol).Value = "- seit -" 'place text into last column
```

If have a feeling its causing problems because its a formatted table but I am not sure about that. I am very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it stops because its a table. Check if value exist and if no again check for last column same way only not Columns.Count but from the LastColumn.

Answer (score 0):

Read the comments and adjust it to fit your needs

```
Public Sub InsertColumnValue()
    
    ' Set a reference to the table
    Dim targetTable As ListObject
    Set targetTable = Range("TableName").ListObject
    
    ' Find last row in column A
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = targetTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(targetTable.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - targetTable.HeaderRowRange.Row

    ' Add data to next empty row
    ' Do something
    
    ' Check if last column in last row is empty
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    If targetTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(lastRow, targetTable.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count).Value = vbNullString Then
        lastColumn = targetTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(lastRow, targetTable.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Else
        lastColumn = targetTable.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count
    End If
    
    ' Add value to next empty column in next empty row
    targetTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(lastRow + 1, lastColumn + 1).Value = "- seit -"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the next function, please:

```
Function LastUsedColInTable(tbl As ListObject, iRow As Long) As Long
 Dim C As Range

 With tbl.Range.rows(iRow)
    Set C = .Find(what:="*", After:=.cells(1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
             searchorder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not C Is Nothing Then
        LastUsedColInTable = C.Column
    Else
        LastUsedColInTable = 1
    End If
 End With
End Function
```

It can be tested in this way:

```
Sub testLastColInTable()
 Dim tbl As ListObject
 Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
  Debug.Print LastUsedColInTable(tbl, 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: @DXR: You received some answers. Didn't you find some time to test them? If yes, some feedback should not kill anybody...